# submit form when checkbox change in the same php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

i have this code:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();">
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</form>


<?php if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
echo "ok";} ?>
```

but the post of the checkbox doing nothing

can you help me 
sorry im newbie

Comment: so where's the jquery that goes with this? you also tagged as CI. Look at you console.

Comment: ^^ and you're forgetting the action tag which. Maybe consider PHP SELF for this page

Comment: you have no php tags around your php

Comment: it doesnt work ...

Comment: Works for me: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/testcheckbox.php

Comment: @Barmar please give me the code :) doesnt work in my webserver

Comment: I simply copied your code, and added a `<script>` tag to load jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar can you write me the correct code in an answer ? thanks a lot

Comment: The code is exactly the same as the code you posted. All I did was put boilerplate like `<html><body>` around it, and add the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>` tag to load jquery.

Comment: @Barmar sorry but im a newbie and im not understand, can write me with the details ?

Comment: I've posted my code in an answer. But since it's essentially identical to yours, it doesn't really explain what you're doing wrong, so I'll delete it after you get a chance to look at it. You should post your entire script, so we can see what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact code that I tested and it works.

When it's displaying the form, it uses `isset($_POST['checkbox'])` to decide whether to add `checked="checked"` to the HTML, so it remembers what the user's choice was. Then the PHP code at the end does different things depending on whether it's checked.

```
<html>
<body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</form>


<?php
     if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
         echo "box is checked";
     } else {
         echo "box is not checked";
     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/testcheckbox.php)

Comment: it works thanks ! but if the checkbox is checked="checked" its doesnt work

Comment: Only checked boxes are sent to the server. So if the box is not checked, `isset()` will be false. If the box is originally checked in the HTML, clicking on it unchecks it, so nothing is sent in `$_POST['checkbox']`.

Comment: So it only prints `ok` when the user checks the box, not when the uncheck it.

Comment: I need that also when you unchecked the checkbox the program do something...its possible ? @Barmar

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how it can remember whether the box is checked, and show a different answer depending.

Comment: I understand ;) but i need a dinamically check box that when is change from checked to unchecked update a query

Comment: I showed how to do that. You update the query one way if it's set, update it the other way if it's not set.

Answer (score 0):

lot of solutions but here the fast one :

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: i tested in chrome & Firefox , you may use IE , am I right?

Comment: copy and paste my code and check it again , i tested in chrome it is fine

Comment: if you insisted to use JQuery , your code is fine just check if you include the JQuery library correct , put it between head tags